# Orderer not created

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I try to setup a Hyperledger fabric with 4 organizations and 6 peers. The problem is that docker-compose.yaml seems to be creating everything, but when i check with docker ps, the orderer and peer0.org3 are not there.

with docker logs orderer.example.com the error that i have is:

> Failed to initialize local MSP: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory

with docker logs peer0.org3.example.com the error that i have is:

> Error loading secure config for peer (error loading TLS key (open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key: no such file or directory))
>
> version: '2'
>
> networks:
>    basic:
>
> services:
>     ca1:
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
>       environment:
>         - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca1
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/82db4322a70d36be7f9edd0277098a4361890218c2042b8f9e6c4fbab2d6e5ce_sk
>       ports:
>         - "7054:7054"
>       command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
>       volumes:
>         - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
>       container_name: ca1
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> ca2:
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
>       environment:
>         - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca2
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ee3cdbd1af237db4358761271ac0c8ab3c483b129621753bc99a5caabe7c9247_sk
>       ports:
>         - "7055:7055"
>       command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
>       volumes:
>         - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
>       container_name: ca2
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> ca3:
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
>       environment:
>         - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca3
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0a7870dc9412f3eb1fc83eab808dcc556ffd5a48e37f703288b12f524c5656f9_sk
>       ports:
>         - "7056:7056"
>       command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
>       volumes:
>         - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
>       container_name: ca3
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> ca4:
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
>       environment:
>         - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca4
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org4.example.com-cert.pem
>         - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0f64dba89d3d86396cbfc0fcbf37b204e1c051fd19d227f035108b834629f7f3_sk
>       ports:
>         - "7057:7057"
>       command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
>       volumes:
>         - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
>       container_name: ca4
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> orderer.example.com:
>       container_name: orderer.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
>       environment:
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
>         # enabled TLS
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
>         - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
>         - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
>       command: orderer
>       volumes:
>         - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>         - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
>         - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
>       ports:
>         - 7050:7050
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer0.org1.example.com:
>       container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 7051:7051
>         - 7053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer1.org1.example.com:
>       container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 8051:7051
>         - 8053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer0.org2.example.com:
>       container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 9051:7051
>         - 9053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer1.org2.example.com:
>       container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 10051:7051
>         - 10053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer0.org3.example.com:
>       container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 11051:7051
>         - 11053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> peer0.org4.example.com:
>       container_name: peer0.org4.example.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
>       environment:
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
>         # bridge network as the peers
>         # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
>         - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=supplychain_basic
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
>         #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
>         - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
>         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org4.example.com
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org4.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org4.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org4.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org4MSP
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: peer node start
>       volumes:
>           - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
>           - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
>           - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>       ports:
>         - 12051:7051
>         - 12053:7053
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> couchdb:
>       container_name: couchdb
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
>       # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
>       # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
>       environment:
>         - COUCHDB_USER=
>         - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
>       ports:
>         - 5984:5984
>       networks:
>         - basic
>
> cli:
>       container_name: cli
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
>       tty: true
>       environment:
>         - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
>         - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
>         - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
>         - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
>         - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
>         - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
>         - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
>         - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>       command: /bin/bash
>       volumes:
>         - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
>         - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
>         - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
>       networks:
>         - basic

Comment: have you make sure that the mappings of those files are correct?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not generated the crypto materials for the org3 and the orderer properly. Check crypto-config once and see if its properly created or not.